# How do can I use a trained machine learning model as the objectve function for an optimization problem in Pulp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, optimization, pulp

I have asked about this problem before on stackoverflow and could successfully use a linear regression model as the objective function for optimization. However, this was easily done as I could access coefficients and intercept of the model and form the linear regression equation. Now, the question is how it can be done if the model is random forest? Is it even possible to use such a machine learning model as the objective function in an optimization problem?

I set the problem as:

```
model_problem = pulp.LpProblem("Minimize the value", pulp.LpMinimize)
```

Then I use the data set of the inputs (a Pandas DataFrame) to form the variables:

```
V = []
for i in range(df_in.shape[1]):
    v = pulp.LpVariable(df_in.columns[i],lowBound=range_min[i],upBound=range_max[i])
    V.append(v)
```

in which `range_min` and `range_max` are two lists which define the bounds for the inputs variables. `df_in.columns` provides the names of the variables. 
At this point, I am trying to define my objective function. What I know is that if I had a linear function such as: `y = 2*X + 3` as the objective function, I could do:

```
model_problem += 2*X + 3
```

and then add the constraints subsequently as well. But the only possible way that comes to my mind, when dealing with a trained machine learning model is:

```
def objective(V):
    return M.predict(V)
```

in which `V` is the list of variables to be fed to the machine learning model. and then:

```
model_problem += objective(V)
```

However, all of this does not work. The very issue that I face is the fact that I can only feed actual float values to the ML model and I cannot use it to set the objective function. At least I do not know how and I am hoping you would be able to help a little bit. 
I am using `Pulp` for the optimization process but I am open to other options as well. I tried to use the same strategy with `Scipy.optimize.minimize` but I could only use `COBYLA` method in which you cannot enforce constraints or bounds.

Comment: You should be aware that Pulp only supports linear objectives, i.e. `sum(i, c[i]*x[i])`. PuLP is for LP/MIP models only.

Comment: I see. So is there any other way that I can form this problem?

Comment: In general, you probably would need to look at a DFO (Derivative Free Optimization) solver.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen - Thank you for the suggestion. I did some search and it seems like it's a good method for some black box function to be optimized.

Comment: @AradHaselirad did you find how to  define objective function. I am working on similar problem  where I have trained using random fores and  how to set constraint for categorical variables?

Comment: @BharatSharma I ended up defining the objective function with the machine learning model but could not use Pulp. I could use scipy.optimize.minimize package.